# my Bluetooth cannot connect to the device

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

i am trying to use my android phone to connect to the pc or hc01 but know the code that i write cannot connect to the phone now so anyone can help me out
and the UUID what should i use or have anyone have some demon for me to try out 
thanks

i don't why i click and it always connect fail and the logcat will get

```
com.example.lord1.myapplication123123 W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
```

this is my code:

```
private void discover(View view){
    // Check if the device is already discovering
    if(mBTAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Discovery stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        if(mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mBTArrayAdapter.clear(); // clear items
            mBTAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discovery started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            registerReceiver(blReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

final BroadcastReceiver blReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // add the name to the list
            mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            mBTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
};

private void listPairedDevices(View view){
    mPairedDevices = mBTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // put it's one to the adapter
        for (BluetoothDevice device : mPairedDevices)
            mBTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Show Paired Devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

        if(!mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bluetooth not on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        mBluetoothStatus.setText("Connecting...");
        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        final String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
        final String name = info.substring(0,info.length() - 17);

        // Spawn a new thread to avoid blocking the GUI one
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run() {
                boolean fail = false;

                BluetoothDevice device = mBTAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

                try {
                    mBTSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    fail = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // Establish the Bluetooth socket connection.
                try {
                    mBTSocket.connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        fail = true;
                        mBTSocket.close();
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, -1, -1)
                                .sendToTarget();
                    } catch (IOException e2) {
                        //insert code to deal with this
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Socket creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                if(fail == false) {
                    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mBTSocket);
                    mConnectedThread.start();

                    mHandler.obtainMessage(CONNECTING_STATUS, 1, -1, name)
                            .sendToTarget();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post log starting from the `onClick` event. And add `logs` in your code instead of `Toasts`, easier to follow the `log`.

Comment: i don't know how to put tranform to service this code is write the bluetooth on the smae page and if i change page the bluetooth will close the bluetooth